Is it legal to pass a const pointer to a struct and a pointer to its member as non-const?
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} my_struct_t;

void f2(const my_struct_t *my_struct, int *b)
{
    *b = my_struct->a + 1;
}

void f1(my_struct_t *my_struct)
{
    f2(my_struct, &(my_struct->b));
}

The my_struct parameter in f2() is declared as const so none of its members can be modified, but the b parameter is a pointer to a member of my_struct which is modified.
I wonder if, according to the c99 standard, the way I called f2() is legal or could lead to undefined behavior?

This behavior is allowed.
The const qualifier on the first parameter says the struct it points to cannot be modified through that pointer.  It doesn't prevent the member from being modified through a non-const pointer.
And because the object itself is not const qualified, it is allowed to modify *b in the function.
In fact, because of that, it would also be allowed to cast the my_struct parameter to a non-const pointer and modify the members that way, although doing so would generally be considered bad form.

it would also be allowed to cast the my_struct parameter to a non-const pointer and modify the members that way, although doing so would generally be considered bad form - I thought that converting a const pointer to non-const was illegal in c99 as it would result in undefined behavior.

@ParminderSingh It's only undefined behavior to cast and subsequently modify if the object itself is const.


Is it legal to pass a const pointer to a struct and a pointer to its member as non-const?

Sure.

The my_struct parameter in f2() is declared as const so none of its members can be modified

No. The pointer is declared as pointing to const, so no members can be modified using this pointer without casting const away. A const pointer does not really imply that the pointed-to memory is const or not.

I wonder if, according to the c99 standard, the way I called f2() is legal or could lead to undefined behavior?

Is legal.

Further
Note that void f2(const my_struct_t *my_struct, int *b) allows my_struct and b to point to overlapping areas of memory.
One pointer my_struct is restricted in that via that pointer, a modify attempt causes an error like "error: assignment of read-only location".
The other pointer b is not restricted.  It may modify the data.

If f2() is only for pointers to non-overlapping data, use restrict to enable additional optimizations and potentially warn about overlapping data.
void f2(const my_struct_t *restrict my_struct, int *restrict b) {
  *b = my_struct->a + 1;
}

void f1(my_struct_t *my_struct) {
  f2(my_struct, &(my_struct->b));  // UB
}


*1Interestingly  casting away the const like ((my_struct_t *) my_struct)->b = 42; is OK if the caller's my_struct_t was not const and UB if it was.

Good point regarding the restrict, could you explain me what do you mean with "is OK if the caller's my_struct_t was not const and UB if it was"?

Maybe I understood what you mean, if f1() was declared like void f1(const my_struct_t *my_struct) then calling f2() like this f2(my_struct, &(my_struct->b)) will lead to an UB?

@ParminderSingh Concerning casting away const, with void f1(const my_struct_t *my_struct), and f2(), it is UB with const my_struct_t cx; f1(&cx); and OK with my_struct_t x; f1(&x);.  The issue is the top level object - is it const?

No the top level object is not const.
